# Jsoup parse not nested tags

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to parse items from one site. I reached the goal, but i'm losing a lot of informations, because i can't parse it with my method. Right now after JSOUP API i'm replacing symbols to tags for creating certain format, that i can use to iterate by tags and sort them to arrays.

So, the action chain : `jsoup html > jsoup text > string replaces > jsoup html`.

I think that everything what I was doing with text I could do with JSOUP easily. But, unfortunately, i'm new with this library and can't use it rightly.

How it works now. I have a string. If I use html() i will see:

```
<i>Требования:</i>
<br>
<i>Эффект:</i>
<br>- Увеличивает МА: 45
<br>- Увеличивает ФЗ: 57
<br>- Увеличивает МЗ: 57
<br>- Увеличивает Земля: 15
<br>- Увеличивает Воздух: 15
<br>- Увеличивает Вода: 15
<br>- Увеличивает Огонь: 15
<br>- Срок жизни: 720
<br>
```

If i use text() then result will be:

```
Требования: Эффект: - Увеличивает МА: 45 - Увеличивает ФЗ: 57 - Увеличивает     МЗ: 57 - Увеличивает Земля: 15 - Увеличивает Воздух: 15 - Увеличивает Вода: 15 -     Увеличивает Огонь: 15 - Срок жизни: 720
```

I use bunch of replacements to get something, that i can iterate

```
String htmlAddMoreBR = html.replace("\t\t","<br>");
String htmlAddClass = htmlAddMoreBR.replace("<br>- ","</span><span class=\"item\">");
String htmlReplaceI = htmlAddClass.replace("<i>","</span><span class=\"group\">");
String htmlDeleteBR = htmlReplaceI.replace("<br>","");
String htmlReplaceStrongOpen = htmlDeleteBR.replace("<strong>","<span class=\"item\">");
String htmlReplaceStrongClose = htmlReplaceStrongOpen.replace("</strong>","</span>");
String htmlRemoveSec = htmlReplaceStrongClose.replace(" сек.","");
String htmlRemoveMeters = htmlRemoveSec.replace(" м.","");
String htmlReplaceСommaToDots = htmlRemoveMeters.replace(",",".");
Document document = Jsoup.parse(htmlReplaceСommaToDots);
Elements elements = document.select("span");
```

Result of my replacements

```
</span><span class="group">Требования:</i>
</span><span class="group">Эффект:</i>
</span><span class="item">Увеличивает МА: 45
</span><span class="item">Увеличивает ФЗ: 57
</span><span class="item">Увеличивает МЗ: 57
</span><span class="item">Увеличивает Земля: 15
</span><span class="item">Увеличивает Воздух: 15
</span><span class="item">Увеличивает Вода: 15
</span><span class="item">Увеличивает Огонь: 15
</span><span class="item">Срок жизни: 720
```

I created 3 HashMaps **optReqList**, **effList**, **currentList** (oups, forgot to change name,nvm). I iterate by span if I get the **REQUIREMENT** key word, then `currentList = optReqList`, if get **EFFECTS** key word, then `currentList = effList`, else pushing to currentList new items, that i found by their key word.

And it works. But! This method with replacements doesn't allow me to parse **level**, **desc** and **comp []**. And also the code is so dirty.

** **Example, where my replacements don't work.**

```
<i>Набор предметов для 3 уровня специализации "Инквизитор". Дешевле на 25%, чем тот же набор, покупаемый по отдельности.</i> 
<br> 
<i>Состав:</i>
<ul>
<li>Клепанный шлем Инквизитора</li>
<li>Клепанный пояс Трибунала</li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
```

Result of replacements.

```
</span><span class="group">Набор предметов для 3 уровня специализации     "Инквизитор". Дешевле на 25%. чем тот же набор. покупаемый по отдельности.</i> 
</span><span class="group">Состав:</i>
<ul>
<li>Клепанный шлем Инквизитора</li>
<li>Клепанный пояс Трибунала</li>
</ul>
```

I really need you help. **How to properly parse all items by using JSOUP, that represented on image below?**

```
<strong>Item:Level</strong>
<i>Description. Bunch of text here.</i> 
<br> 
<i>Composition</i>
<ul>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
</ul>
<br>
<i>Requirements:</i>
<br>
- Item1Name:Item1Value
<br>
- Item2Name:Item2Value
<br>
- Item3Name:Item3Value
<br>
<i>Effect:</i>
<br>
- Item1Name:Item1Value
<br>
- Item2Name:Item2Value
<br>
- Item3Name:Item3Value
<br>
- Item4Name:Item4Value
<br>
```

Also I createrd document for better understanding relations between image and code of this item. [Google Docs Document. Examples.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1q5vfAbixOL3ulBtG_K7Q67XAXH49jYphC5UPoFASvcw/edit) And Repository: [SimpleParserGamexp](https://bitbucket.org/darkDesire/simpleparsergamexp) with full source code.
[image: Picture.Examples of items]

Comment: The problem seems to be that the info you want to extract is not well structured in html. I don't think that transforming the inner html to (invalid) html and then parsing it with Jsoup helps your case much. I would instead leave the original html, parse it with Jsoup and then write a specialized parser for the inner html to fill your data structures.